# Avoiding stacking and tangling paths when making paths and join them with shape builder tool properly in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I tried to make a logo properly using circles and lines, and then combining them with Shape Builder tool instead of tracing the sketch manually, but I am left with nasty tangling stacking paths and points.

[image]

---

What I was up to is dividing circles by 15 degree and use shape builder tool to my liking.

[image]

---

My question is why this happens and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your corners are set to `Miter Join`. You can fix this by:

Going to `Window` > `Stroke` or **<kbd>Ctrl/Cmnd</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>** and change the corner to either `Round Join` or `Bevel Join`

[image: Stroke Panel in Illustrator CS6]